# Почему не переключается язык (Django)?

Tags: django

Добрый день. В документации Django был предложен код для переключения языков. Собственно, вот он:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Нет, не забыл {% load i18n %}. Да, подключил LocaleMiddleware в settings.py.

Для полноты картины сливаю urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')), # остальные url'ки
)
```

И что же происходит при запуске? А ничего. Выбираем нужный язык, нажимаем на кнопку и кроме перезагрузки страницы никаких действий и изменений. Язык благополучно сменяется только при ручном редактировании URL в адресной строке.
Что-то пересматриваю и не понимаю, что забыл-то?

./manage.py show_urls

```
/en/    app.views.home      
/en/<category_slug>/    app.views.categories    categories  
/en/<category_slug>/<article_slug>/ app.views.artices   articles        
/en/media\/<path>   django.views.static.serve       
/i18n/setlang/  django.views.i18n.set_language  set_language    

... # все ссылки, связанные с админкой

/ru/    app.views.home      
/ru/<category_slug>/    app.views.categories    categories  
/ru/<category_slug>/<article_slug>/ app.views.artices   articles        
/ru/media\/<path>   django.views.static.serve
```

При смене языка в Network'e сначала появляется setlang/ со следующим статусом:

[image: setlang/]

Далее за ним появляется язык, который был выбран до переключения. В данном случае переключение было на английский, но остался все равно русский со следующим статусом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу добавить, что без url_patterns переключение работает на ура. Также если он включен и в адресной строке стереть язык, то после перезагрузки выдаст именно тот, который был отправлен в переключателе (т.е. вытаскивается из кеша или сессии). Где-то проблема с url_patterns или что-то не подключено.

Comment: Неплохо было бы глянуть на исходник страницы, которая генерится по Вашему коду. Это важно. Посмотреть можно в инструментах разработчика в любом браузере. Особое внимание форме переключения.

Comment: Надеюсь Вы об этом (добавил фото в описании вопроса).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275486/django-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-urlpatterns   ./manage.py showurls покажите :)  как в посте @Seti Volkylany

Comment: Добавил в описание вопроса

Comment: В urls нет i18n ... Но по идее middleware может обходиться и без urlpatterns, потому в консоли разработчика браузера нет кодов перенаправления при смене языка? Должно работать как HttpRedirectResponse, соответственно и код ответа сервера на 200

Comment: *первый ответ сервера.

Comment: Добавил. Посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: Так у Вас в settings указаны все коды языков?

Comment: Ну да.
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', 'Русский'),
    ('en', 'English'),
)